# How do you position a MathJax element within a box using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to position a MathJax element within a box. I have tried several different methods but none work. The box itself gets positioned but I want the element that is appended to the box to be positioned within the same box (#third). The code so far actually moves the entire third box not the element that is being appended to the third box. Here is the Javascript/JQuery code. The complete code can be viewed at the following link: [MathJax Code](http://web.ncf.ca/~eh936/Files/MathJax%20Drag%20and%20Drop%20-%20Working%20Code.html)

function drop(ev) {

```
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

//ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

switch(data)
{
       case("drag1"):

         $('#second').append('$$\\sum$$');
         break;

   case("drag2"):

     $('#second').append('$$\\int$$');
         break;

       case("drag3"):

     $('#second').append('$$\\alpha$$');
         break;

       case("drag4"):

     //$('#second').css("font-size","150%");
         $('#second').append('$$\\beta$$').css("font-size","150%");
         break;

        case("drag5"):

         $('#second').append('$${du}$$');
         break;

        case("drag6"):

         $('#second').append('$${dt}$$');
         break;

        case("drag7"):

         $('#second').append('$${t}$$');
         break;


       case("drag8"):



          //$('#second').append('$$\\beta$$').css("font-size","150%");
          //var $sqrtEqElement = $('#third').append('$${t}^x\\sqrt{t}^x$$').css("font-size","100%"); 
          //var $sqrtEqElement = document.createElement("$${t}^x\\sqrt{t}^x$$");
          //$('#sqrtEqElement').parent().css({position: 'absolute'});
          //$('#sqrtEqElement').css( { position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0} );

          $('#second').append('$${t}^x\\sqrt{t}^x$$');
          $('#container').append('<div id="third" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>');

          $('#third').append('$${t}^x\\sqrt{t}^x$$').css( { position: 'absolute', top: 10, left: 100} ); //not working

          //$('#third').append('<label>Filename:</label> <input type="text" name="file"  id="file" />');

          break;

       default:
    }
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"second"]);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"third"]);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following :

```
  var text = '<span style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 100px;">$${t}^x\\sqrt{t}^x$$</span>';
  $('#third').append(text);
```

Comment: thanks @madalin but the above code still moves the entire box and not the appended symbol.

Comment: you want the appended simbol?

Comment: thanks @madalin. Yes I need to be able to move the appended symbol within the box only not the box itself in which the symbol is appended to.

Comment: $('#third').append('$${t}^x\\sqrt{t}^x$$').css( { position: 'absolute', top: 10, left: 100} );                                                                                                               Thanks Mandalin. Mandalin any ideas why the above code would not work ? Also with respect to the code you just posted that works how can I treat the parameter of the append as a variable ?

Comment: the code in you comment does not work because you are not appending a element to the div but text , and in this chaining you are not referencing the appended text  but the div ,what i did in my answer i created a styled span and wrapped the text

Comment: Thanks again @mandalin. But is it also possible to break the above span and its properties into variables ? For example can you create a variable for the position property which is used in the <span> tag in the above code ?

Comment: mandalin one more question. You said "he code in you comment does not work because you are not appending a element to the div but text" does this mean that it is not possible to use the original code or any close variation that I had posted ?

Comment: you can use a variation of you code where you wrap the appended text into span's ,and yes you can create variables for the position property or any property of the span